# Can't boot after Kubuntu 13.10 installation with Windows 8 Dual Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, windows-8

I installed Kubuntu 13.10 with Dual Boot Windows 8.1 via USB.
After reboot i got the prompt: `Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported`

I already tried to fix it with boot-repair, but nothing changes.
the output of boot-repair is: [paste.ubuntu.com/7245898](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7245898)

any ideas what's wrong?

thanks!